# Most elegant way to sync managed objects with controls on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm trying to port an iPhone application from using SQLite to Core Data.

Is there a way to sync managed objects directly with the controls that manipulate their values, without having a controller in the middle?  Note: I CAN do it the hard way -- it's what I'm doing now; I'm looking for the elegant, easy, fast way.

I'm paging through the documentation and I'm just starting to feel overwhelmed.  The documentation on Bindings seems to be Mac OS X only, not iPhone.  Is what I describe even possible on the iPhone?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: hoping for some more useful suggestions.  There's usually more than one way to do these things.

Comment: Don't forget to credit me with the answer ;)

Comment: Which answer is that, Mr. Didn't Magically Solve All My Problems and Make Me an iPhone Millionaire Overnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unfortunately correct. Unless there's some library I don't know about (not impossible), you get to roll your own binding of coredata classes to views.

Comment: Any rumors about Apple adding it in later?

Core Data looks awesome, but if you have to insert an intermediary controller object in the middle, it loses a lot of its elegance.  Granted, the MVC model is good, but the Bindings mechanism essentially *acts as the "C"* for those cases where more complex handling is not needed.

Comment: I would imagine they're going to, since that seems to be what they do: release a library, wait a year or so for it to bake in, and then send it over to iPhone. Approximately 30% of WWDC iPhone content consisted of "now on iPhone!".